# Check if request is coming from Windows application

Tags: c#, php

I have got a .php file which generates a XML file. I'm using this XML in my C# application and I want to check within this .php file if request is coming from windows application because I don't want users to view this page in browser. Please help me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding some keyword for getting that xml file? make some password to take that xml with, and request php file like myxml.php?key=mykeywordishere, keyword can be encoded with some md5 it it matters.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way might be calling the php script with a certain key as secret parameter.

```
www.myweb.com/myfunction.php?pass=secretPassword
```

This key will be harcoded in the call from your #C application.

Then you could just check if the password is the one you expect with something like:

```
//hardcoded hashed pass with sha1, for example.
$myHashedPass = '40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef';

if(sha1($_GET['pass']) != $myHashedPass){
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a special user agent in the headers for the request, so you could check, for example, of the user agent is "My C# Application". If it is not, the request was not issued by your application.

See the [HttpRequest.UserAgent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx) property on how to change the user agent. In PHP, use this to get the user agent string:

```
$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use a custom **User-Agent** string and also set the **Content-Type** to something like `"application/octet-stream".`

Or use a hardcoded password in your C# application.

If security is important you should also use **HTTPS** cause all the previous information could be retrieved by someone who has a basic understanding of Wireshark or any similar program.