# PHP - check json value after one hour

Tags: php

I have created a function, which get twitter count using json.

But, I want to recheck it agian after some time, like an hour. But currently it checks every time when a page loads. and which effect page loading time.

there is already a PHP function which do exactly what i want, but I cant remember it, I just remember that the function start from `tr....`

Here is my function, which check twitter follower :

```
function follower( $tw ) {      
    $tw =  @json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name='.$tw));
    $tw_followers = number_format($tw->followers_count); 

    return $tw_followers;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I found that PHP function:

```
set_transient('follower', $tw_followers, 60*60*24);
```

please guide me if I am wrong

Comment: why not just use `Cron Job` or  `Scheduled Task` ?

Comment: this is a simple thing, I dont want to use corn, corn will make thing complicated. and dont want to use database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of [cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron_%28Unix%29) if you are using a Unix server or Windows Task Scheduler in the case of windows.

Like this you will be able to use programmed tasks.

For windows here's a tutorial apported by @Chris Cooney: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-automate-windows-programs-on-a-schedule/

In the case of using cron you could do it easily like this to check it every hour:

```
0 * * * *  php -f your_relative_or_full_path_URL/params > /dev/null
```

To avoid anyone to execute the code by URL, you could something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15618074/1081396).

Comment: You are right, but I dont want to use corn or schedule, cuz currently i am not using database for it. if i use task schedule then i need to save data on database

Comment: No. Cron is not related with database at all. You don't need a database to execute a schedule task.

Comment: OK, I will check it. It is a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the time using time() will allow it to run every hour if the page is loaded. You will also need to store a value in a database of when it was last run. Below is some pseudo code mixed with PHP

```
connect_to_database();
$lastcheck = get_value_from_database('last-check');
if($lastcheck+3600 < time()) {
  run_json_stuff();
  update_last_check_in_database();
}
```

the $lastcheck+3600 = 1 hour since last run. If it is less than time() which is when the page is loaded, it has been over an hour since it has ran last, so it should run again.

Comment: Good answer for when Cron or Windows scheduler is not available. Also should be noted you can simply store lastcheck value in file, not necessarily database (just need to make sure concurrency is dealt with).

Answer (score 1):

You can use mem cache or some other cache technology to queue up all your JSON key/values and run a background thread to grab those values every hour.

Comment: I was thinking you were using C# to run the job for some reason. If you are using PHP & HTML5, you can make use of local storage and save the user object for an hour and then destroy it after that. So each time the page loads, it looks up the local storage instead of making a request to twitter rest api.

Comment: localStorage['jsoncache'] = JSON.stringify(myJSONObject);

to retrieve the object.

myJSONObject = JSON.parse(localStorage['jsoncache']);

Answer (score 0):

Use **AJAX** to get it and reload your page with correct value in a frequent interval.