# Limit Api Calls, api is in a php template

Tags: php, api, cdn, rate-limiting

I am trying to limit how often an api call is made.

The api call is in a page template

```
<?php   

$producturl = 'theapiurl';
$product_json = file_get_contents($producturl); 
$product_array = json_decode($product_json, true);  
$price = min(array_column($product_array['products'][0]['offerData']['offers'],'price'));
?>

some html
<?php echo $price ?>
```

What i want is that the api is only called once every 12hours for example (the data doesnt change often)
and that if the template is loaded a second time in that 12hours, that the api is not called again, but the $price output should still work.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is still too broad even after revision. Question is, how are you going to call the code? From command-line, is it part of website, etc?

Comment: i had all that info in my original post to be honest.
it is on a website, in a php page template. so everytime a visitor goes page x, this script/template is run
I need the data from the api call to generate the page, but the data does not change often. so grabbing the data once every 12h and using that data for 12h long would be fine. Just not sure what i want is possible

Comment: sure it is possible, but in general for things like that you wouldn't call them directly from webpage, but instead from Cron job or Windows scheduler. If you need this to remain inside the web page, which can be called by anybody at will, you just need to put in some time tracker that makes the page not call API when called more than once per day. You do need to be able to write the time into external file or database, to check against.

Comment: Basically what you need is one of the solutions listed here https://stackoverflow.com/q/16190783/50003 you can also use file instead of database if you don't have access to one or don't want to use one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what access you have to the server and how easy/quick it is to get fresh data.

You could do as suggested by Gnudiff, and use a cron command to fetch the data on a schedule, then store it in a database, for you to return in each response.

Or you could use an in memory store like Redis to cache the data. When a user calls the endpoint, you check the cache to see if it exists. As it won't exist, fetch your data, store it in the cache with a TTL on the data that expires at the end of the 12hr period, and return it to the user. The following requests all follow the same process, returning it from the cache if it exists, or getting the data for fresh if it doesn't, and then returning it to the user.

Comment: I have full acces to the server, but never worked with anything like memory storing with redis before (i am really really new to a lot of this) 
I will probably use the cron method. store it in my database, serve the content from there and overwrite the data in the database every 12h-24h.  That sounds like something i should be able to do